# Local Client Time in Flask

Tags: python, flask, web-applications

I have a flask todo list app with due dates. The due dates are basically timestamps you want to complete the todo by.

It sends a push notification when the current time has surpassed the due date of the todo. The due dates are entered in Year-Month-Day Hour:Min (24 hour time) format. It's working fine right now on my machine but if I were to deploy it on a server, it compares the server's time to the due date. I want to get the client/browser's time. How can I do that?

Here is my Python code

```
@app.route('/dashboard', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def dashboard():
    incomplete_todos = Todo.query.filter_by(writer=current_user, complete=False).all()
    complete_todos = Todo.query.filter_by(writer=current_user, complete=True).all()

    return render_template('dashboard.html', incomplete_todos=incomplete_todos, complete_todos=complete_todos, datetime=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Here is my HTML/Jinja Code

```
{% if datetime >= todo.due_date %}
    <meta http-equiv="refresh">
        <script>
            Push.create("Overdue Todos", {
                tag: 'overdue',
                body: "Your overdue todos are listed below.",
                icon: '../static/todos.png',
                timeout: 5000,
                onClick: function () {
                window.focus();
                this.close();
              }
            });
        </script>
        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle important"></i>
        <a class='edit' href="{{ url_for('edit_todo', todo_id=todo.id)}}"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></a>
        <a class='complete' href="{{ url_for('complete_todo', todo_id=todo.id)}}"><i class="far fa-check-square"></i></a>
        <a class='delete' href="{{ url_for('delete_todo', todo_id=todo.id)}}"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
        {% else %}
            <a class='edit' href="{{ url_for('edit_todo', todo_id=todo.id)}}"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></a>
            <a class='complete' href="{{ url_for('complete_todo', todo_id=todo.id)}}"><i class="far fa-check-square"></i></a>
            <a class='delete' href="{{ url_for('delete_todo', todo_id=todo.id)}}"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
        {% endif %}
```

Don't worry about the Push.create stuff, that's what I use to throw a push notification but my main question is how can I get the client/browser time in flask and then put it in the html to compare it? I want to also have it in the same format.

Comment: Have you tried to convert every timestamp to UTC in your database and then localize it to your time zone in your app?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, DateTime in the server is in UTC, so it is a good practice to save all DateTime in UTC.

Regarding your question, if you store all DateTime in UTC, you do not need to convert to client time to judge whether the task is to out of date or not. because if it is out of date according to UTC in sequence it will be out of date in the client time, where you compare todo time in UTC with the current time in UTC too.

So when the client inter the DateTime, we should convert it to UTC DateTime before saving, but in case we knew the client time difference.

But, how can we get client DateTime difference? it is not related to the location of the client, but, related to the client's computer setting.

Therefore, the only client computer can tell us the time difference, which, could be by using javascript running on client browser which sends client time difference to flask server.

In order to get the client time server, I follow an indirect way in which I ask an Html page `send_client_time_diff.html` to give the time difference to a view function `dashboard` (for example) in a variable `sent_to="dashboard"`.

```
return  render_template('send_client_time_diff.html',sent_to='dashboard')
```

This Html page has javascript that open window (redirect in the same window) and fire the function stored in the variable `sen_to`

The content of the `send_client_time_diff.html` page is:

```
<script>
    var date = new Date();
    var diff = date.getTimezoneOffset();
    window.open("{{url_for('receive_client_time_diff')}}?diff="+diff);
</script>
```

In turn, the view function `dashboard` handles the time difference sent sored in the parameter `diff`

I will assume the view function `dashboard`as follows:

```
@app.route('/dashboard', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def dashboard():
    diff = request.args.get('diff', None, type=int)
    server_time = datetime.utcnow()
    client_time = server_time - timedelta(minutes=diff)
    text= f'client datetime : {client_time}  & server datetime : {server_time}'
    return  text
```

we should notice that the page `send_client_time_diff.html` does not wait for client reaction, it redirects automatically to fire the view function in `sent_to`

But if we want to make the modification for the function in question, in case you store client time without converting to UTC, it would be:

```
@app.route('/dashboard', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def dashboard():

    diff = request.args.get('diff', None, type=int) ###

    incomplete_todos = Todo.query.filter_by(writer=current_user, complete=False).all()
    complete_todos = Todo.query.filter_by(writer=current_user, complete=True).all()

    datetime_client=datetime.datetime.utc_now()-datetime.timedelat(minutes=diff) ###

    return render_template('dashboard.html', incomplete_todos=incomplete_todos, complete_todos=complete_todos, datetime= datetime_client)
```

looking forward to any comments